# Form stuck in PENDING status with async validator when value changed on construction

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

When using reactive forms with an async validator on the form group, and if changing the values of the form group by using `patchValue` in the constructor or in `ngOnInit` - even though the async validator observable completes, the form remains in `PENDING` state.

I've created a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-validator-stuck-in-pending-state)

In the example, you see a simple form with two fields, with an indication of the form status, and the validator state. In the code, in `ngOnInit` I call `patchValue` on the form, causing the form to go into `PENDING` status, and the async validator to be called.

The async validator doesn't do much, it simply waits for 1 second then returns a `null` errors object basically saying that the form is valid. You can see in the indications that the validation completed, but the form stays in `PENDING` status.

If you trigger a change in field values at any time other than in the constructor or in `ngOnInit` (i.e. on object construction) - then the form does go into `VALID` status when the validator completes. This also applies if you wrap the value change in `setTimeout`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this normal behavior, or is this a bug in Angular?

Comment: I can't pinpoint exactly what is going on and which values are stuck in pending state, but I can say that it definitely has to do with the fact that angular forms are asynchronous, so when you call `patchValue` "too fast" (before the form has been completely built and prev values set), it causes this. So no, not a bug, it is caused by angular forms being asynchronous. There are sometimes other issues caused by forms being asynchrnous, so you sometimes need to wait a tick (using settimeout) before doing something, here's one (unrelated) question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58578113/6294072

Comment: Thanks @AJT82 I would say it's either a feature (possibly undocumented) or a bug. If it's a feature it should be described in a specification, if it's a bug it should be opened as an issue. But anyway, I would put in a warning either in runtime or during compile that `patchValue` shouldn't be called in the same frame that creates the `FormGroup`...

Comment: in if case i was sending values but  I was missing below code in else case.   observer.next(null);
 observer.complete();
 return { unsubscribe() { null } };

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, after async validator, form stuck on PENDING and this is how I deal with it:

1) make observable of status change:

```
this.form$ = this.form.statusChanges;
```

2) subscribe to observable:

```
this.form$.subscribe( r => {
  if (r === 'VALID') {
    //form valid
  } else if( r === 'PENDING') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.form.updateValueAndValidity(); // this function will trigger statusChange one more time.
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    // any other status
  }
});
```

So if async validator finished but didn't trigger statusChange then all You can do is trigger statusChange one more time by Yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue solved it by using a **debounceTime** like so:

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(400), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(val => {
if (!this.form.pristine) {
    if (val.Name && this.form.valid) {
        this.portalInfo['Name'] = val.Name;
    }
}});
```